# How to use dependencies and modules in play-framework 2.0

Tags: scala, module, dependencies, sbt, playframework-2.0

Currently in playframework 1.2.4 there is a such thing like *module* and *project*, if a project depends on a module, user should put appropriate line in configuration, into dependecies.yml file.

Now, as I can see, reading exiting documentation, there is an idea if *subprojects* 
`/<my_home>/play/documentation/manual/build/SBTSubProjects.md` instead of modules??

Taking into consideration that now there is no 'dependecies.yml' file anymore, I would say that idea of suprojects is going to substitute the modules?

Then, what I do:

```
cd projects
play new newProject
mkdir modules
cd modules
play new project1
play new project2
play new common
```

vi /projects/newProject/project/Build.scala

editing it like this:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "newProject"
  val appVersion = "1.2"

  val common = PlayProject(
    appName + "-common", appVersion, path = file("modules/common")
  )

  val project1 = PlayProject(
    appName + "-project1", appVersion, path = file("modules/project1")
  ).dependsOn(common)

  val project2 = PlayProject(
    appName + "-project2", appVersion, path = file("modules/project2")
  ).dependsOn(common)

  val main = PlayProject(
    appName, appVersion
  ).dependsOn(
    project1, project2
  )
}
```

But, then ... if I try to run 'project1':
 cd /projects/newProject/module/project1

```
play run
```

It would know nothing about the dependency to 'common' project for 'project1' (i guess), because I did not modify project1/project/Build.scala ..

So, what I should do with that? How 'project1' would know about its dependencies in run-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found only one solution for now:
 just make a link in `newProject/modules/project1/modules/common` to ->  `/newProject/modules/common`